# ubuntu 12.04 windows 8 UEFI dual boot

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

A friend has a new laptop with windows 8 pre-installed and he'd like to install Ubuntu like a second operating system.
I recommend him to use the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS because he is a new ubuntu user and LTS distributions in my opinion are more stables than the normal distributions.

Well, my question is if it's possible to install dual boot windows 8 with UEFI and ubuntu 12.04. Someone can explain the steeps to do?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The bootloader that came with Ubuntu 12.04.1 (and 12.04) does NOT support UEFI. However Ubuntu 12.10 does. You can also wait for three days to get Ubuntu 12.04.2, which will have support for UEFI.

Comment: As far as I know, only the 64bit (called AMD64) Ubuntu 12.10 supports UEFI.